# Copy folder and all subfolders but NOT symlinks

Tags: windows-7, symbolic-link

I need to copy a folder and all of its subfolders but I don't want any of the symlinks or their contents to come with it.

Can this be done simply?

Or - obviously - can I easily disconnect and remove all symlinks from a folder hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

The command-line utility robocopy.exe (included in Win7) has the option **/sl** which
"Copies the symbolic link instead of the target.".

That result should be very close to what you have asked for.

See also [Robocopy parameters help](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the idea but it won't work in my case. I need the symlinks to not be there at all in the copy.